# ¿Cómo ocultar un aside con posición absoluta y CSS Grid

Tags: javascript, css, scss, grid

Estoy tratando de ocultar un aside pero al intentar aplicar la clase CSS con javascript no funciona, no entiendo por que no aplica la clase a mi elemento `wrapper`.

Quiero mi `wrapper` se ponga por encima del aside como el del ejemplo

¿Donde se encuentra el error?
Este es el ejemplo del que me estoy guiando.

> https://codepen.io/blackvolta/pen/ribJF?editors=1100

#### Index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="./node_modules/normalize-css/normalize.css"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="wrapper">

      <aside>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Home 4</a></li>
          </ul>
      </aside>
      <header>
      </header>
    <main>
      <button onclick="x()"> click me</button>
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
    <script>
        function x(){
          var element = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper");
          element.classList.add("closed");
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### SCSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  border: solid 10px blue;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(11, 1fr) 250px;
  grid-template-rows: 60px auto 100px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "h h h h h h h h h h h a"
    "c c c c c c c c c c c a"
    "f f f f f f f f f f f a";
  grid-row-gap: 15px;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 150px;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: right 0.9s ease;
  aside {
    grid-area: a;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(0, 136, 170);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  header {
    grid-area: h;
    background-color: aquamarine;
  }
  main {
    grid-area: c;
    background-color: burlywood;
  }
  footer {
    grid-area: f;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
  }
}

.closed {
  .wrapper {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el CSS estabas indicando en la clase .closed que debe buscar dentro de este elemento otra clase llamada .wrapper esta no existe por lo tanto eliminamos la clase wrapper del css.

La propiedad de right la cambié por `width: 0 !important;`, para que sobrescriba sobre la clase anterior

En el HTML tenías la función `getElementsByClassName()` te devuelve varios elementos y para poder llamarla puedes usar la variable `elemento[0]`, pero lo ideal es usar IDs para seleccionar un elemento en JS, lo que hice fue cambiar esta función por `getElementById()` y ponerle un id al elemento de sidebar.

Luego esta línea `element.classList.add("closed");` la puedes sustituir por `element.classList.toggle("closed");` `toggle()` te permite añadirle y eliminarle la clase cuando des click.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    ul {
      list-style: none;
    }
  }
  
  h1 {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  body {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .wrapper {
    border: solid 10px blue;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(11, 1fr) 250px;
    grid-template-rows: 60px auto 100px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "h h h h h h h h h h h a"
      "c c c c c c c c c c c a"
      "f f f f f f f f f f f a";
    grid-row-gap: 15px;
  
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: right 0.9s ease;
    aside {
      grid-area: a;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: rgb(0, 136, 170);
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }
    header {
      grid-area: h;
      background-color: aquamarine;
    }
    main {
      grid-area: c;
      background-color: burlywood;
    }
    footer {
      grid-area: f;
      background-color: cornflowerblue;
    }
  }

  .closed {
      width: 0 !important;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="./node_modules/normalize-css/normalize.css"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="wrapper">

      <aside id="wrapper">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Home 4</a></li>
          </ul>
      </aside>
      <header>
      </header>
    <main>
      <button onclick="x()"> click me</button>
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
    <script>
        function x(){
          var element = document.getElementById("wrapper");
          element.classList.toggle("closed");
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias!  El problema de ocultar un div con width: 0 es que los elementos se empiezan a encojerse y no se ve muy agradable por eso no lo quiero ocultar con width 0, estoy pesando como ocultar el aside y se vea bonito a la vez

Comment: Puedes aplicarle otra clase con JS a el elemento ul y ponerle un display: none o un opacity: 0

Comment: La propiedad display:none, no se puede animar, opacity 0 tampoco me sirve, hace el mismo efecto con los elemntos se van achicando poco a poco tambien se va degradando el color hasta no verse, mi fondo es negro y se va aclarando hasta ponerse blanco :(

Comment: Vale, aplica estos estilos: al <body> le pones un overflow: hidden; a los elementos <li> width: 120px; o la medida que quieras darle y un margin: auto;